# Correct Permissions in shared apache folder

Tags: permissions, apache2

I'm trying to have a PHP development environment that handles multiple projects automatically without creating a separate vHost for each project, this part works fine.

I go through all the steps that i have done:

1. I have created a directory called `sandbox` in my home directory and symlinked it to `/var/www/sandbox`

   ln -s ~/sandbox /var/www/sandbox
2. then I have created an apache config file in `sites-avaialble` and enabled it, this config file is a virtual host that will point every `.test` domain to `/var/www/sandbox/` directory, for example if you browse `http://wordpress.test` it will point to `/var/www/sandbox/wordpress`

All these parts works fine but the problem is with permissions, I'm creating my projects from my home directory (~/sandbox) and in every product that i create, PHP files don't have write access so i have to chown every file and directory of the project to `www-data` user manually or with a bash script.

I have tried changing owner of `sandbox` directory to `www-data` but it doesn't have any affect, again every folder that i create in this directory has permission issues.

**Edit:**

What i exactly want to achieve is that when I create a project under `~/sandbox` directory I don't have to manually fix file ownerships/permissions, right now for example when I want to create a WordPress project i have to run [this script](https://gist.github.com/macbleser/9136424) in order to fix permissions in a way that i can create new folders (themes and plugins) and also php files have write access so WordPress functionalities works correctly

Comment: You don't have to create a folder `sandbox` in your home to create the symlink. It will be "covered" by the symlink anyways, that is why a change of permissions or ownership to that folder doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @cyberbrain should I do the opposite? I mean create a symlink to /var/www/sandobx (actual directory) in my home directory?

Comment: Aaah - I think it was a misunderstanding. Probably it would be the better option to create /var/www/sandbox with the right permissions and symlink to it, but it is not essential. I thought you created _both_ as folder and then used symlink - should have known better as symlink would fail in that case...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Apache server on your machine only for development, you could try to let it run as your local user.

For this, adjust the `APACHE_RUN_USER` in your /etc/apache2/envvars.

I would not touch the group, and there is the risk that you have to change many ownerships or permissions afterwards, and make sure that your apache server cannot be reached over the network from "outside". (E.g. by letting it only listen to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

The root directory should always have **EXECUTE** permission and index file should have **READ** permission

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/root-directory
```

Also, add ownership for the directory

```
sudo chown -R user:group /path/to/root-directory
```

Finally, restart the apache web server,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Adjust the directives in the web server configuration,

```
<Directory "/var/www/sandbox/wordpress">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please upvote this answer

Comment: How does this solve the problem of needing to chown/chmod newly created files?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the group ownership of `/var/www/sandbox` to `www-data`, then enable writes and [setgid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#SGID) recursively on the directory. The setgid bit causes the group owner of all newly created items in a directory to be the same as that of the parent, which is `www-data` in our csae. You can/should leave the user owner as your own user.

```bash
# Make you the owner and `www-data` the group owner of /var/www/sandbox
sudo chown -R <your user>:www-data /var/www/sandbox

# Give owning user and group read/write permissions, remove all permissions for everyone else
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o= /var/www/sandbox

# Enable the setgid bit on /var/www/sandbox and all descendant directories
find /var/www/sandbox -type -d -exec sudo chmod g+s {} \;
```